# Can someone please tell what is wrong in this(Run time error)(want to get the maximum number out of all four integers)

Tags: c++, runtime-error

**This Question is from Hacker rank Function in C++ section**
I am getting the answer that i want but the output is repeated so many time that i have to stop the code from running manually

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <cstdio>
    using namespace std;
    
    int max_of_four(int a,int b,int c,int d){
        if (a>b){
            cout<<a;
        }else if(b>c){
            cout<<b;
        }else if(c>d){
            cout<<c;
        }else if(d>c){
            cout<<d;
        }
        return max_of_four( a,  b,  c,  d);
    }
    
    int main() {
        int a, b, c, d;
        scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
        int ans = max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
        printf("%d", ans);
        
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: max_of_four should not print anything, only return the selected value.

Comment: `return max_of_four( a,  b,  c,  d);` looks like a problem as well. This is a function calling itself--that can be useful, but only the outgoing call is different from the incoming call in a way that eventually leads to the calls stopping.

Comment: Can you explain how you think the logic should work? The function will call itself forever since there's no exit condition. Not sure why it prints the value instead of returning it either. Initialize a variable called `ret` with the value of `a`, then if `b` is larger than `ret` set `ret` to the value of `b` and so on for `c` and `d`, then return `ret`. (You can pick your own name for the variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have written `max_of_four()` as a **recursive** function. It calls itself over and over in an endless loop, and it is printing on each iteration. The function should not be printing anything at all (the caller is printing the value that is returned), and it certainly should not be calling itself at all.

Also, the logic is just plain wrong. It doesn't actually report the largest value of the 4 values given. For instance, if `a>b` is true then it doesn't even consider the values of `c` and `d` at all, which might be larger than `a`. And similarly, if `b>c` is true then the value of `d` is not considered.

The correct logic would look more like this:

```
int max_of_four(int a,int b,int c,int d){
    int max_value = a;
    if (b > max_value){
        max_value = b;
    }
    if (c > max_value){
        max_value = c;
    }
    if (d > max_value){
        max_value = d;
    }
    return max_value;
}
```

Which can be simplified using the [`std::max()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) algorithm, eg:

```
#include <algorithm>

int max_of_four(int a,int b,int c,int d){
    return std::max(a, std::max(b, std::max(c, d)));
    // Or: return std::max({a,b,c,d});
}
```

Alternatively, using the standard [`std::max_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) algorithm, eg:

```
#include <algorithm>

int max_of_four(int a,int b,int c,int d){
    int arr[] = {a,b,c,d};
    return *std::max_element(arr, arr+4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the recursive call you are making inside of `max_of_four()`. What you should do is replace the `cout` (which prints the result) with `return` statements. Edit the code to look like this instead:

```
int max_of_four(int a,int b,int c,int d){
    if (a>b){
        return a;
    }else if(b>c){
        return b;
    }else if(c>d){
        return c;
    }else if(d>c){
        return d;
    }
}
```

There is a logical problem as well, this code wouldn't work if, for example, `d` is the greatest number but `a>b` is `true`. But that's a separate issue. At least this is the explanation why you get the same answer over and over again.

Comment: If no value is greater than any other value, the return value will be indeterminate, since that code path has no `return` value. The compiler should be warning you about that. Also,the code is wrong anyway, as it doesn't actually return the greatest value of all 4 parameters.